# Odata sample service not working

Tags: odata

OData sample service is not working for me.

Is it happen for me only ?

http://services.odata.org/v3/odata/odata.svc

Comment: Sorry about this. The problem is known and we're working on fixing it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If possible please update me once its up

Comment: Do we have any other free sample service which is working ?

Comment: I don't know of any other sample services, but if you're just wanting to play around with URI syntax or explore what various payloads look like, you can check out a public real OData service, like StackExchange's [here](http://data.stackexchange.com/meta/atom). For other public services, go to the Producers section this page: http://www.odata.org/ecosystem/

Comment: Huh, it looks like the stack exchange link I provided yesterday is now also down.  I'll let you know as soon as the main samples server comes back up.

Comment: *Ma'am ;) The sample services are back up now. Sorry again about the outage. We're looking into moving these services to a more stable location so this doesn't happen anymore.

Comment: Is it possible that service can be blocked by Firewall...as I am able to open the service on my machine but unable to open at company machine ?

Comment: Yes, it might be blocked by your company's firewall. I would check with your IT department.

Comment: Thanks for checking with my IT department ;)